# JPA not updating ManyToMany relationship in returning result

Tags: jpa

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Actor {

    private List<Film> films;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="film_actor",
    joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="actor_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="film_id"))
    public List<Film> getFilms(){
        return films;
    }

//... more in here
```

Moving on:

```
@Entity
public class Film {

    private List actors;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="film_actor",
            joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="film_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="actor_id"))
    public List<Actor> getActors(){
        return actors;
    }
//... more in here
```

And the join table:

```
@javax.persistence.IdClass(com.tugay.sakkillaa.model.FilmActorPK.class)
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "film_actor", schema = "", catalog = "sakila")
@Entity
public class FilmActor {
    private short actorId;
    private short filmId;
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;
```

So my problem is:

When I remove a Film from an Actor and merge that Actor, and check the database, I see that everything is fine. Say the actor id is 5 and the film id is 3, I see that these id 's are removed from film_actor table..

The problem is, in my JSF project, altough my beans are request scoped and they are supposed to be fetching the new information, for the Film part, they do not. They still bring me Actor with id = 3 for Film with id = 5. Here is a sample code:

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class FilmTableBackingBean {

    @Inject
    FilmDao filmDao;

    List<Film> allFilms;

    public List<Film> getAllFilms(){
        if(allFilms == null || allFilms.isEmpty()){
            allFilms = filmDao.getAll();
        }
        return allFilms;
    }
}
```

So as you can see this is a request scoped bean. And everytime I access this bean, allFilms is initially is null. So new data is fetched from the database. However, this fetched data does not match with the data in the database. It still brings the Actor.

So I am guessing this is something like a cache issue.

Any help?

Edit: Only after I restart the Server, the fetched information by JPA is correct.

Edit: This does not help either:

```
@Entity
public class Film {
    private short filmId;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "films", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Actor> getActors(){
        return actors;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JB Nizet is correct, but you also need to maintain both sides of relationships as there is caching in JPA.  The EntityManager itself caches managed entities, so make sure your JSF project is closing and re obtaining EntityManagers, clearing them if they are long lived or refreshing entities that might be stale.  Providers like EclipseLink also have a second level cache http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Only after adding 'em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); to getWithId in filmDao I was able to see the change. But is this the only way to do? How will I know when to clear the cache, and when to not? Can I disable cache for good to make sure? ( I am already keeping data in memory anyway if db is not changing between requests.. )

Comment: Sorry, it appears it was because ActorDao and FilmDao both extended from GeneralDao, and they did not have their own Entity Managers.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping is wrong.

The join table is mapped twice: once as the join table of the many-to-many association, and once as an entity. It's one or the other, but not both.

And the many-to-many is wrong as well. One side MUST be the inverse side and use the `mappedBy` attribute (and thus not define a join table, which is already defined at the other, owning side of the association). See example 7.24, and its preceeding text, in [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e11384) (which also applies to other JPA implementations)

Side note: why use a short for an ID? A Long would be a wiser choice.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to let you know that, even when I have situation 2 ( '@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "films")' ), it did not work. Am I doing something wrong? Only after adding 'em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();' to my getWithId method in filmDao , I was able to see the change.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my comment. It turns out, because I am extending from a GeneralDao ( FilmDao and ActorDao ) they were somehow sharing the same EntityManager. I did not need to clear the cache when they had their own EntityManagers.. Thanks again!